# How break page after my element in xsl-fo

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I use this code for apache xsl-fo:

```
<xsl:template match="depFileNom">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="1cm"
                                     margin-left="2.7cm"
                                     margin-bottom="2cm"
                                     margin-top="2cm"
                                     page-width="21.5cm"
                                     page-height="29.7cm"
                                     master-name="first">
                    <fo:region-body margin-right="1cm" margin-left="0cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-after">
                <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="10pt"><fo:page-number /></fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>

            <fo:block font-family="Times" font-size="15pt">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="10000px" text-align="left"/>
                        <fo:table-body>                       
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border-style='none' vertical-align='middle'><fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="year" /> year</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                         </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
I want to break here
...
```

I think need to use:
    page-break-before
    page-break-after
But i don't know how
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure because your FO is incomplete, but try adding the attribute `page-break-after="always"` to the `fo:block`. If you're trying to break after the `fo:table`, and there are following siblings in the same `fo:block`, try moving the `page-break-after="always"` to the `fo:table`.

Depending on your data, you may also want to consider using different `fo:page-sequence`'s for the different pieces of content.